# OpenGL рендер поверх всего

Tags: c++, opengl, графика, шейдеры

Всем привет, мне нужно рендерить дистанции до объектов поверх всего
Если это делать после рендера всей сцены с отключенным тестом глубины `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`, тогда все работает, однако мне нужно делать это раньше (в целях оптимизации).

Есть такой код:

```
void Application::RenderPlanetSatelliteDistances() const {
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    for(const auto& renderableComponentPS : _renderableComponentsPS) {
        if (isRenderPlanetDistances) {
            RendersSpaceObjectDistance(renderableComponentPS.planet);
        }

        if (isRenderSatelliteDistances) {
            for(const auto& satellite : renderableComponentPS.satellites) {
                RendersSpaceObjectDistance(satellite);
            }
        }
    }

    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
void Application::RendersSpaceObjectDistance(const std::shared_ptr<SpaceObject>& spaceObject) const {
    for(const auto& renderableComponentPS : _renderableComponentsPS) {
        deque<wchar_t> distanceInfo(spaceObject->GetEngName().begin(), spaceObject->GetEngName().end());

        if (!spaceObject->GetOtherLangName().empty()) {
            distanceInfo.push_back(L'[');
            distanceInfo.insert(distanceInfo.end(), spaceObject->GetOtherLangName().begin(), spaceObject->GetOtherLangName().end());
            distanceInfo.push_back(L']');
            distanceInfo.push_back(L' ');
        }
        wstring distance(to_wstring(static_cast<uint16_t>(CalculateSpaceObjectDistance(spaceObject))));
        distanceInfo.insert(distanceInfo.end(), make_move_iterator(distance.begin()), make_move_iterator(distance.end()));

        _mainTextShader->Use();
        _mainTextShader->SetVec3("particleCenterWorldSpace", spaceObject->GetPosition());
        _mainTextShader->SetBool("is3D", true);
        _textRenderer->Render(*_mainTextShader, distanceInfo, 0.f, 0., 0.075, glm::vec3(0.98431, 0.80784, 0.69412)); // RGB: 251 206 177
    }
}
```

Если этот метод вызывать после всей сцены, как я уже сказал, то всё норм, но если его вызывать вперемешку с рисованием других объектов, то текст перекрывается теми объектами, которые рисуются после него (вызываются позже):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А. Правильный вариант - как вы сказали, делать это после рендера всей сцены с отключенным тестом глубины `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`.

Б. Менее правильный, можно, к примеру, рисовать в другой буфер и в конце накладывать его на основной.

В. Можно сохранять команды на отрисовку в какой-нибудь "список", и в конце рендера их оттуда вызывать на отрисовку после всего.

Г. Можно рисовать текст без полупрозрачности (забыл как режим Alpha_Test называется?) с указанием Z близким к камере, и тогда другие объекты (будучи дальше от камеры) не будут рисоваться поверх.

Comment: Ну вот из всех вариков самый адекватный А и Г, конечно, на мой взгляд..Ладно, лишний цикл не шибко режет фпс, оставлю А, чтоб велосипед не выкручивать

Comment: Если у вас планируется GUI, то как раз в его слое все эти надписи и должны быть )